# Google changes my page title in search results

Tags: search-engine, title

When I search in google for this query
"site:www.peled-security.com"
it shows me that almost all the pages has " - X" at the end.

[image: screenshot of the "- X"]

And when I view the page source - it doesn't have this " - X"

```
<title>הגעה-פלד סקיוריטי</title>
```

I tried looking for this character in the page-source,
and I've tried to search for how google changes the title - and couldn't find anything.
Why is that happening?

Comment: is there anyone in here??

Comment: this is still happening, i need your help!!